Reference request for a formula on volume of balls and spheres
Let $b_n$ be the $n$-dimensional volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $s_n$ be the $n$-dimensional volume of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Using their expression in terms of the Gamma function (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Volume_and_area) and Legendre's duplication formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function%E2%80%93Legendre_formula) one can prove the following (in my opinion elegant) formula:
$$ \frac{n! b_n s_n}{(2\pi)^n}=2 $$
I find this formula convenient to switch from $b_n$ to $s_n$, however I have been unable to locate a good reference for it. Again, it is not difficult to prove, but if I could avoid taking unnecessary space in my article, it would be nice. Does anyone know a good reference I could cite?
Edit: phrasing, it looked like I was trying to avoid specifically Gamma functions.

Equivalently$$u_n:=b_nb_{n+1}=\frac{(2\pi)^n2}{(n+1)!}.$$It's not hard to show$$b_{n+1}/b_n=\operatorname{B}\left(\frac12,,\frac{n+2}{2}\right),$$so$$u_{n+1}/u_n=\operatorname{B}\left(\frac12,,\frac{n+2}{2}\right)\operatorname{B}\left(\frac12,,\frac{n+3}{2}\right).$$Now you just need to prove$$\operatorname{B}\left(\frac12,,x\right)\operatorname{B}\left(\frac12,,x+\frac12\right)=\frac{\pi}{x}$$without the Gamma function (I don't know how, but maybe you can request a reference for that), then use induction.

On second thoughts$$\frac{b_{n+2}}{b_n}=\int_{x^2+y^2\le1}(1-x^2-y^2)^{n/2}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$is easily evaluated in polar coordinates without Beta or Gamma functions, namely to $\frac{2\pi}{n+2}$, so $v_n:=b_ns_n=(n+1)b_nb_{n+1}$ turns out to satisfy $\frac{v_{n+1}}{v_n}=\frac{2\pi}{n+1}$ as required.

Thanks for the comment. However, I am not really looking for a new way to prove it, the proof with Legendre's duplication formula is fine as it is in my opinion. I was more asking for a reference that I could cite so I can avoid proving it. Not because I don't know how, but because I don't want to take unnecessary space in an article if I can avoid it.

The statements in the first half of the question seem sufficient justification for using this formula in a paper. You don't need further details of the proof. For that reason, I think you'll have trouble finding a reference that gives a more complete proof. Who would use that much space in their publication for such a thing?

Thanks for your comment. Indeed, this is what I usually do. However I would feel more comfortable if there was a more detailed proof. Maybe in a reference book or something.
